# SharePoint Page Versioning Disabled

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I was looking for different page designs and I tried one. But now I am not able to go back to the original one as I don't have the permission (although I am the owner) or maybe it was never turned ON.
How can I restore the original page?

[image: Page manage properties are disabled]

Comment: Check for Version history and see if you can restore earlier versions.

Comment: @JohnZachariah where I can find version history? The one in the picture is disabled for me

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see from your screenshot, try Edit Page and then you should see Lay-out in the ribbon. If you go to Site Content, Site pages, look for the specific page and using the ellipsis you should be able to find Version History.